# How can I create an array of 1-element arrays from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to be able to convert arrays, such as

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
```

into the same array BUT each element as a 1-element array instead of a number. 
The desired output would be:

```
np.array([[np.array([1]), np.array([2])], [np.array([3]), np.array([4])]])
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It seems unnecessary and counterproductive in just about all situations. Perhaps you need to add an extra dimension to your array (`a[..., None]`), or perhaps the [array scalar](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) mechanics let you do what you need to do with your original `a`.

Comment: Also, to clarify; does `np.array([[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]]])` match what you want, or do you actually want an array with other arrray objects in it instead of a 3-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you describe is very rarely useful. More likely, it would be a better idea to add an extra dimension of length 1 to the end of your array:

```
a = a[..., np.newaxis]
# or
a = a.reshape(a.shape + (1,))
```

Then `a[0, 1]` will be a 1D array, but all the nice NumPy features like broadcasting and ufuncs will work right. Note that this creates a view of the original array; if you need an independent copy, you can call the `copy()` method.

If you actually want a 2D array whose elements are 1D arrays, NumPy doesn't make that easy for you. (It's almost never a good way to organize your data, so there isn't much reason for the NumPy developers to provide an easy way to do it.) Most of the things you might expect to create such an array will instead create a 3D array. The most straightforward way to do it I know of is to create an empty array of object dtype and fill the cells one by one, using ordinary Python loops:

```
b = numpy.empty(a.shape, dtype=object)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        b[i, j] = numpy.array([a[i, j]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array([ [ [x] for x in row ] for row in [[1,2], [3,4]] ])
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what behavior the OP is looking for, but even if this produces it, it's a horrible way to go about it. Using list comprehensions defeats almost all the benefits of NumPy.

Comment: Numpy is great for the mathematical manipulation of arrays (dotproducts, transposition, multiplication, etc.), but if you aren't doing one of those things, you can just do it in python.

Comment: You can do it in Python, but you'll bloat your code horribly and eat a factor of 1000 slowdown over `array[..., None].copy()` or an even bigger slowdown over just creating a view with `array[..., None]`. NumPy can do a lot more array shape manipulation than just `thing.T`.

Answer (score 0):

You are fighting `np.array`s attempt to create a high dimensional array.

For example, your desired expression, when entered, produces a (2,2,1) array:

```
a2 = np.array([[np.array([1]), np.array([2])], [np.array([3]), np.array([4])]])

In [172]: a2
Out[172]: 
array([[[1],
        [2]],

       [[3],
        [4]]])
```

Which might actually be what you want (despite print appearances), since

```
In [180]: a2[0,0]
Out[180]: array([1])
```

Often the best way to fight the tendency of `numpy` to make a higher nd array, is to initialize it as empty with the right `shape` and `dtype`, and then fill it:

```
In [183]: a1=np.empty(a.shape,dtype=object)    
In [184]: a1.flat=[np.array(x) for x in a.flatten()]
In [185]: a1
Out[185]: 
array([[array(1), array(2)],
       [array(3), array(4)]], dtype=object)
```

It has the right shape (2,2), and dtype.  The elements are arrays - but their dimensions are 'wrong', `()` instead of `(1,)`.  `flat` and `flatten` are handy tools for iterating over nd arrays as though they were 1d.

`a1.flat=[np.array([x]) for x in a.flatten()]` does not work - it's an array of `ints` like `a`, but with object dtype.

A more explicit iteration does work:

```
In [214]: a1=np.empty(a.shape,dtype=object)
In [215]: for i in np.ndindex(2,2):
    a1[i]=np.array([a[i]])
In [216]: a1
Out[216]: 
array([[array([1]), array([2])],
       [array([3]), array([4])]], dtype=object)
```